# How to drop a column if the row value is less than 1000000

Tags: python, pandas

I've been reading and trying for hours...
I have a df like this:

```
                             BTC/USDT  ...                 MOVR/USDT
symbol                       BTC/USDT  ...                 MOVR/USDT
timestamp               1636391714488  ...             1636391711813
datetime     2021-11-08T17:15:14.488Z  ...  2021-11-08T17:15:11.813Z
close                65826.8800000000  ...            403.4000000000
percentage               6.0380000000  ...              4.4540000000
baseVolume           50096.1040200000  ...         111340.7360000000
quoteVolume     3255082473.3960447311  ...       46765144.8117000014

[7 rows x 349 columns]
```

I'm trying to drop columns where the 'quoteVolume is less than 1000000

I got this far...

```
        a = df.loc['quoteVolume'] > 10000000
        print(a)
       
BTC/USDT         True
ETH/USDT         True
BNB/USDT         True
BCC/USDT        False
NEO/USDT         True
                ...  
AUCTION/USDT    False
DAR/USDT         True
BNX/USDT        False
RGT/USDT        False
MOVR/USDT        True
Name: quoteVolume, Length: 349, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

A bool mask does the trick:

```
df.loc[:,df.loc[('quoteVolume',:]>1000000)]
```

Comment: No that does not work for me.. I get  `raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'quoteVolume' `

Comment: Try now. It should work better now

Comment: I still get....  df.loc[:, df.loc[('quoteVolume',:] > 1000000)]
                                                  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  ..... I'll keep trying

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 9hrs of trying.

```
 a = df.loc[:,df.loc['quoteVolume'] > 1000000]
 print(a)
```

Finally working

Comment: what column is being drop if the quoteVolume > 1000000.  How did you decide

Comment: Since quoteVolume is a index, I assume he drop the entire column which meets the requirement.